# Why is the "Add" VPN button grey?

Tags: 12.04, vpn

[image]

I wanna click on the "Add" button but I can't :l Pleases help!

Comment: Do you have the following packages installed? `network-manager-openvpn, network-manager-openvpn-gnome, network-manager-vpnc, network-manager-vpnc-gnome`? If not try to install them.

Comment: next time make it an answer @thomas :D I made it up to you if you know what i mean ;)

Comment: @Thomas No, I don't, how do I install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have no software installed for VPN.

If you need Cisco Open Connect you can use ...

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

There are more packages all depending on a specific VPN or on a group of VPNs (that use the same method).

4 (well 2: openvpn and vpnc where 1 of each is for gnome) of them listed by Thomas in comment ...

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

But don't install them all, pick the one you need for your specific VPN. And all the "vpn" names are listed behind the "network-manager-" (mind the second "-") so they are easy to search in Ubuntu software center.

Comment: Do I put in "network-manager-openconnect-ghome" in Terminal? I did and it says "command not found"

Comment: Oh wait but you gave me 4 of those things, you told me not to install them all, which one do I install? By the way I need it for letting Google think that I'm in another country because in this country I can't monetize my YouTube channel. So which one should I install?

Comment: Oh wait but you gave me 4 of those things, you told me not to install them all, which one do I install? By the way I need it for letting Google think that I'm in another country because in this country I can't monetize my YouTube channel. So which one should I install?

Comment: @EmilyShan you need the one your vpn on the other side wants. Start with "openvpn(-gnome)"  then "vpnc(-gnome)" .

Comment: This is what I see in my Terminal:                                                                              First line: ceibal@ceibal:~$ openvpn(-gnome)
Second line: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-gnome'
Third line: ceibal@ceibal:~$

Comment: By the way I'm **very** confused, I'm not good with my Ubuntu so please explain everything if you can.

Comment: Dont forget the command in front to install software. You can also search for `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` in Ubuntu software center and install from there (might be easier ;-) )

Comment: I searched for `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` in Ubuntu Software Center and it came out one thing and I clicked on `Install` and I put the password three times (correctly) then it doesn't install it nothing happened :(

Comment: So what command (exactly) do I use? Sorry I'm very confused with these stuff...

Comment: Well thanks a lot for helping, I just don't like to leave people like this. I got a Windows computer so... Well thanks a lot anyways!! :)

Comment: @EmilyShan thanks for the upvote. I never saw you post what vpn you need but the 1st of the 4 listed at the bottom looks like it is used most.